# With ProGuard, how do I obfuscate just one class?

Tags: proguard

What would be a smart ProGuard configuration to obfuscate just the private methods and constants of one particular class com.acme.Algorithm?

I would like to obfuscate just that, because it contains an algorithm that should not be plain obvious when accidentally opening the .jar.

I'm a ProGuard newbie. AFAIU, you have to use "keep", but the positive logic of "do obfuscate" is not available, right? So how to exlude my class from a "keep everything" config? Note: I don't want to obfuscate other classes for the moment, because I want to allow the customer to see meaningful stacktraces.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Obfuscating a single class won't have much effect: it may change the class name and a few field names and methods names, and it may optimize some code. Obfuscation tends to be less effective for hiding small pieces of information. The more application code you obfuscate, the more difficult it becomes to understand.

That being said, you can specify:

```
-keep class !com.acme.Algorithm { *; }
```

It keeps all classes/fields/methods outside of com.acme.Algorithm.

Comment: my problem is: it still keep trying obfuscating other classes even I have set above line. how could this happen?

Comment: I am also facing same problem as @Jacky Any pointers to solve the problem

Comment: Obfuscation obfuscates JSON serialized classes and then they can't be mapped to JSON fields. So, obfuscating whole code might cause some problems if serialization is a part of your project.

Comment: For me that script doest work, but this works 
`-keep class !com.acme.Algorithm,** { *; }`. I assume you should also mention what you want to keep and the order is important, first what to exclude and then what to keep.