# Let ProGuard touch only one class

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation

I am working on an app that someone else wrote and i am trying to only obfuscate the classes that I added. I've seen this post: [With ProGuard, how do I obfuscate just one class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880565/with-proguard-how-do-i-obfuscate-just-one-class)

I tried my luck with that (I added a single class and configured ProGuard as shown in the above post) and had only partial success.

It seems like ProGuard is still touching all the other files (md5 hashes change).

This is my ProGuard config:

```
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
-dontnote
-dontwarn
-target 1.8

-keep class !com.example.Test { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also try keeping all the other packages, like:

```
-keep class com.my.example.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a rule containing an exclusion pattern like that:

```
-keep class !com.example.Test { *; }
```

it will internally be treated like this:

```
-keep class !com.example.Test,** { *; }
```

The ** at the end is implicit and doesn't have to be added. Basically you are trying to say "keep all classes except com.example.Test" (and their methods/fields of course).